# Google Marketing Platform And Bigquery- Viewable Impression variance between Offline Reporting and Bigquery Reporting

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, double-click

Currently, I'm trying to set up a replacement for our offline data dump reporting using Bigquery and the data transfer service to eventually export to Tableau.

Everything is working great - aside from one feature, my viewable impression count is always lower in the BQ data than from the Double Click Data. the data dump is pivoted - so the viewable impression count could be an aggregate of viewable Impressions from the impression table and somthing else.

Can anyone shed some light on this - Not sure how or if I can fix this.

Comment: Hi - just to confirm, when you say Double Click data, is this DC data that's been imported into BigQuery, or are you looking at it in DC? Have you exported it manually, or with the data transfer service?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm doing both - so I expect some discrepancy but not as much as I'm currently seeing.

I have CSV's been emailed in with the previous days data that im using for a simple excel analysis using Powerpivot. This is all correct and aligns with the what I can see in the insights page in DCM itself.

the Bigquery data is coming throug the data transfer service > Google Cloyud and then finally Bigquery via the Bigquery data transfer service. everything matches aside from this one metric (basically, I can match, Impressions, clicks, CTR% and interactions.

Comment: Okay, and how much difference are you seeing? Does this difference get less as you look back in time, for example are you seeing the biggest difference in the freshest data? Are you able to share any examples?

Comment: Hi Ben, Sorry - Hit return to Early.

-actually seeing the discrepancy on every day since the 13th of nov and its always negative by about 5-10% in terms of viewable impressions. My understanding is that this shouldnt be possible as whetehr an impression is viewable is stored in line with the impression count itself in another column. therefore it should match, given that the initial Impression count does match.

Comment: Looking at this directly in BQ now - it does seem that the discrepancy is in the data that has been loaded to BQ - Currently running another report from DCM/GMP itself to see whether there are any differences.

It could just be that the data loaded to BQ is being updated and corrected

Comment: Yes this is certainly my experience, data in BigQuery will be overwritten, sometimes several days later, as more numbers drip through from DS. Could this explain the difference you are seeing?

Comment: Chasing this now as an option. anything that's been run as on my CSV's is of course fixed, so if there has been corrections that would explain it.

The other option is that I'm potentially missing part of the Viewable impression metric. I can see you work with GA/BQ. Just wondering whether the viewble impression count as DCM/GMP sees it is a combination of the active_view_viewable_impressions columns and another column.

Comment: Right,

Ran a fresh report from DCM/GMP, and compared vs BQ data - The variance is still there.

Trying to think what else this could be - Do you know if the Viewable Impression Metric is just that column in the Impression table or whether there is an additional data source that feeds in?

Comment: No I am not certain, I;d reach out tot he DS team via email and see if they can advise on this?

Comment: Right reached out and have been forwarded to a specialist team - will update when I have a response as this could well be useful

Comment: Well this is an odd response. Theyre saying that the DCM data is filtered, whilst the BQ data is RAW. But I have more results in the DCM rather than BQ data.

Comment: Well. It certainly seems as if there is a problem.

This has been pushed all the way up to third line now, as the discrepancy is occurring on Googles Side between DCM and DT rather than BQ. hopefully i'll get a response soon, but sounds like this will be long time coming.